# Even though my PATH points to nodejs, node is not recognized. How do I fix this?

Tags: node.js, angular, git-bash

For class we were asked to install Git, Nodejs and VSCode.
After that, we were asked to run npm install -g @angular/cli through gitbash
After waiting a bit, I get an error message:
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.3.14 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.3.14 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JumpNShootMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-26T15_48_32_620Z-debug.log
```

I have tried reinstalling everything and triple checked that the paths were set up correctly. What I don't know is if it's alright for the computer to run some things on Roaming and I don't know if that's my fault. I'm not really good at these things and I'm lost. I thought it would be easy to install :(
Please help

edit: tried reinstalling again, nothing worked. Node as a command is not recognized

Comment: That is probably because you didn't install nodejs as administrator giving it access to all account and there are some permission errors. try running the command from `node cmd`  instead of gitbash if it runs then its a permission issue

Comment: The installer is an .msi file so I cant run it as admin (even though I'm the only admin on the computer :( )
Node says: npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell